# Doctrine 2 ArrayCollection filter method

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, lazy-loading, arraycollection

Can I filter out results from an arrayCollection in Doctrine 2 while using lazy loading? For example,

```
// users = ArrayCollection with User entities containing an "active" property
$customer->users->filter('active' => TRUE)->first()
```

It's unclear for me how the filter method is actually used.

Comment: But still method load to many data, for example for count, load all matching data.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The Boris Guéry answer's at this post, may help you:
[Doctrine 2, query inside entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064528/doctrine-2-query-inside-entities)

```
$idsToFilter = array(1,2,3,4);

$member->getComments()->filter(
    function($entry) use ($idsToFilter) {
       return in_array($entry->getId(), $idsToFilter);
    }
);
```

Comment: The only problem using the filter method is that you have to fetch all the data before you can filter it out, do you know if there is a way of doing this without fetching everything?

Comment: Hi - I'm trying the above but getting a syntax error, can you update your answer?

Comment: @Sjwdavies I updated it for you. Missing () around $idsToFilter.

Comment: Something that bit me is filter returns a Collection. I presumed it returned an array and kept doing $filtered[0], and got null. When I changed the code to $filtered->first() I got the data I expected.

Comment: @ryan's answer about `Criteria` should now (2014) be the accepted answer as it can filter collections at the SQL level.

Comment: @jacobwalker0814 although you are right, this is an old question and the answer back then was the correct one (though now it's obsolete).

Comment: @tftd oh, yeah for sure. My comment meant no disrespect. Instead I meant to notify readers of the newer method that is now available.

Answer (score 139):

Doctrine now has `Criteria` which offers a single API for filtering collections with SQL and in PHP, depending on the context.

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections

**Update**

This will achieve the result in the accepted answer, without getting everything from the database.

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Member {
  // ...
  public function getCommentsFiltered($ids) {
    $criteria = Criteria::create()->where(Criteria::expr()->in("id", $ids));

    return $this->getComments()->matching($criteria); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing out this will actually alter the sql query, rather than selecting everything from the database and then applying a filter via a cycle!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35358597/in-predicate-with-criteria-filtering-isnt-working please, take a look here :)

Comment: There appears to be an issue when using `indexBy="xxx"` on a collection and calling `matching` on it, where the indexes become discarded. https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/4693

Comment: Please Note: `Criteria` works as assumed (SQL instead of filtering via PHP) only if relation declared with `fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"`.

`fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"` doesn't work on every relation yet...

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html

Answer (score 16):

Your use case would be :

```
    $ArrayCollectionOfActiveUsers = $customer->users->filter(function($user) {
                        return $user->getActive() === TRUE;
                    });
```

if you add ->first() you'll get only the first entry returned, which is not what you want.

@ Sjwdavies
You need to put () around the variable you pass to USE. You can also shorten as in_array return's a boolean already:

```
    $member->getComments()->filter( function($entry) use ($idsToFilter) {
        return in_array($entry->getId(), $idsToFilter);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will resolve your need:

```
//$customer = ArrayCollection of customers;
$customer->getUsers()->filter( 
    function (User $user) {
        return $user->getActive() === true;
    }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

The `Collection#filter` method really does eager load all members. 
Filtering at the SQL level will be added in doctrine 2.3.

Comment: is this true now that 2.3 is out? I haven't found it in the docs.
Can we now do stuff like filter and other things, expecting that the collection will apply the filtering to the query and defer the query?

Comment: @Pinetree At least they say so: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections