# Doctrine how to search array of objects?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've array of objects

```
$states = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(LocationState::class)->findAll();
```

How can I check if `$states` contains object with data?

```
LocationState {#102960 ▼
  -id: 1
  -ident: "02"
  -name: "NAME"
  -country: LocationCountry {#102992 ▶}
}
```

This is no ArrayCollection but Array of Objects.

Comment: What do you mean by  `contains object with data` ?

Comment: Yes, exacly. object with spcecific data. I want to check if array contains object with ident == 02 and name == NAME. I can write forech which will be looping for array but I think It's not good idea because of performance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine 2 ArrayCollection filter method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334356/doctrine-2-arraycollection-filter-method)

Answer (score 1):

For array of objects:

```
$found = !empty(array_filter($objects, function ( $obj ) {
    return $obj->name == 'NAME' && $obj->id == 1;
}));
```

For ArrayCollection:

```
$found = $objects->exists(function ( $obj ) {
    return $obj->name == 'NAME' && $obj->id == 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to be retrieved by the query:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(LocationState::class)
  ->findBy(['name' => 'NAME', 'ident' => '02']);
```

If you just want to know if a specified object is on your collection, you will have to use some code

```
 $states = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(LocationState::class)->findAll();

  $found = false;
  foreach($state in $states) {
    if($state->getName() == 'NAME' && $state->getIdent() == '02' ) {
      $found = true;
    }
  }
```

[Doctrine 2 ArrayCollection filter method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334356/doctrine-2-arraycollection-filter-method)

Comment: It's the second issue. I have to find specified object in collection. I've made similar function. I thought that is some kind of php or doctrine helper function to do this. Thanks a lot.