# Extract IDs from ArrayCollection to compare to array of IDs

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Good day,

I have a class **Cars** and class **CarTypes** in a Many-To-Many relation, **Cars** contain an **ArrayCollection** of **CarTypes**. I want to search for Cars satisfying any of multiple selected **CarTypes** (passed from form in array).

Till now I can only think of three nested loops, 1st over Cars, 2nd inner loop over **id**s array (from form) and 3rd inner loop on **ArrayCollection** of **CarTypes** in **Cars** to check if value from 2nd loop exists in 3rd.

I have already checked below links related to closure. But these or none of the links in docs provide sufficient details on how to match an array of selected **id**s against **id**s from **ArrayCollection**.

[Doctrine 2 ArrayCollection filter method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334356/doctrine-2-arraycollection-filter-method)

[Doctrine 2, query inside entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064528/doctrine-2-query-inside-entities)

I have Custom Repositories but feel it better to implement this in **Cars** class using **exists** of **ArrayCollection**, maybe something like following:

```
public function existsCarTypes($ctArray)
{
    $CarTypes = $this->CarTypes;
    return $CarTypes->exists( 
            function($CarTypes) use ($ctArray) 
            {
                if (in_array($ctArray , $CarTypes->getId() )) 
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        );
}
```

But this is not working, Is there a better way to do this, please provide any good documentation links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some other language or architecture it might make sense to implement a Car search as a static method on the Car class. However, the way the doctrine ORM works the right place to implement an entity search is in a custom repository class.

There may be a better way to do a search like this but this is the way I've done it in the past (I'm assuming you know how to add a custom repository to an entity, since you mention them in your question):

```
class CarRepository extends EntityRepository
{ 
    public function findByCarTypes(array $carTypeIds)
    {
        if (!count($carTypeIds)) { return new ArrayCollection(); }

        $carTypesCondition = '';
        $parameters = array();

        for($i = 1; $i <= count($carTypeIds); $i++)
        {
            if (!empty($carTypesCondition)) { $carTypesCondition .= ' OR '; }
            $carTypesCondition .= 'carType.id = :carTypeId' . $i;
            $parameters['carTypeId' . $i] = $carTypeIds[$i-1];
        }

        $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('car')
            ->innerJoin('car.carTypes', 'carType', 'WITH', $carTypesCondition);
            ->setParameters($parameters);

        $query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
        $cars = $query->getResult();

        return $cars;
    }
}
```

NB - I extracted this code from a more complex method so no guarantees that it is error free!

Comment: Thanks redbirdo, It works perfectly, I'm quite new to Symfony2 and Doctrine2 so was thinking more away from query. Since till now I have not been able to understand DQL syntax.